# How to build a dictionary web app for a beginner developer

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js

I am building an online dictionary for spoken Arabic with a search bar and entries for each word.

The options I have thought of are to use wordpress with a custom theme and each word in the dictionary being entered as a post. This seems like a fairly bloated option to me although probably the easiest to set up. The next option is to make the dictionary a single page application using something like Vue.js and if I ever decide to add significant amounts of data like audio files for each word, then connecting that to mongoDB or something similar. Lastly I've also considered using a static site generator like Hugo as the pages themselves do not need to be dynamic for this site.

Comment: You don't need frameworks or libraries for a simple dictionary app. Just need an API to call, so you'll have to learn about HTTP requests and find a source API for your definitions. thats where you should start your research.

Answer (score -1):

There are an infinite amount of options....How about this as a tech stack: I am assuming that this is a personal project and cost needs to be low (free) until your site starts attracting 1000's of visitors a day.

Hosting with Netflify

For a simple backend to read, write and edit entries use Netlify's functions and connect straight to a database like a MongoDB managed by mLabs (they do a free sandbox account.

Front end use React or Vue.js (I use Vue CLI to quickly build sites)

To tie it all together stick it on a private Github account.

Work flow is something like. New project with Vue.cli -> use GitHub account to store the repo. Sign up to Netlify (free) and set it up to build from your Github account when ever you push to Master.

***DONT DIRECTLY QUERY YOUR DATABASE*** from your 'webpage' go via Netlify functions.

All these steps are very well documented and would get you up and running real quick. If your site takes off and attracts loads of people then maybe you can start to swap out tech or use their paid for services. (I'm doing something similar on a few projects, one gets hit a few hundred times a day and its costing me next to nothing)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much for this - it sounds like a sensible approach, I'll give it a try :)